# How to convert this Javascript slider to an OOP solution?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slider

Before explaining the problem, here is a little of context. School wanted us to build from scratch a One Page web resume using only HTML/CSS, Javascript and JQuery.

For that project, I had a lot of ideas. One of them was to use a quote slider. Each x seconds it *slides* to the next quote. So I went looking for something that would work and I found this and adapted it to make it look like :

```js
slideIndex = 1;

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");

  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1;
  }

  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" activeDot", "");
  }

  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " activeDot";
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  showSlides(slideIndex);

  setInterval(() => {
    plusSlides(1);
  }, 5000);

});
```

```css
.sliderContainer {
  position: relative;
  background: #eee;
  /* Not useful here */
}

.slide {
  display: none;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -30px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: #444;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

.next {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  /* Changes color and background color */
}

.dotContainer {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  background-color: #444;
  /* still not useful but I let it */
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.activeDot,
.dot:hover {
  /* changes background-color */
}

q {
  /* changes font-style */
}

.author {
  /* changes color */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-color/2.1.2/jquery.color.min.js"></script>

<div class="sliderContainer">
  <div class="slide">
    <q>A quote</q>
    <p class="author">The quote's author</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <q>Another quote</q>
    <p class="author">The quote's other author</p>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and Right buttons -->
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<div class="dotContainer">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
</div>
```

So, this code works perfectly fine.

But then I wanted to add another slider somewhere else. It was a figure slider and not a quote slider, but that doesn't change anything.
I did build it in the HTML and looked how that work.
And it didn't work correctly because all the slides had the same class. Obviously.

Then I tried changing the classes from `slide` to `quoteSlide` and `figureSlide`. Then I realised I needed to change all the JavaScript related to that.
Well, for only 2 sliders, it doesn't mind. I just did a copy/paste and changed the name of the functions and other small things to get the quote adapted script and the figure adapted script.

But then, I realised I would need a total of **seven** sliders. And I wouldn't get seven times the same script. So I thought and I found an interesting idea.
In my school cursus, we learn a lot of OOP (Object Oriented Programming). But we never talked about it in Javascript class.
So I said to myself, why not trying to do this.

This wasn't the simplest thing to learn, but I managed to get something. Spoiler : this thing didn't work. But here it is :

```
class Slider {

    slideIndex = 1;
    slides;
    dots;

    constructor(index = 1, slides, dots) {
        slideIndex = index;
        slides = document.getElementsByClassName(slides);
        dots = document.getElementsByClassName(dots);
    }

    plusSlides(n) {
        showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }

    currentSlide(n) {
        showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }

    showSlides(n) {
        var i;

        if (n > slides.length) { slideIndex = 1; }

        if (n < 1) { slideIndex = slides.length; }

        for(i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            slides[i].style.display = "none";
        }

        for(i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" activeDot", "");
        }

        slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
        dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " activeDot";
    }

    setupSlider() {
        showSlides(slideIndex);

        // Sliding automation
        setInterval(() => {
            plusSlides(1);
            console.log(this.slideIndex); 
        }, 5000);
    }
}
```

And here is the code in the main JS file :

```
let quoteSlider     = new Slider(1, ".quoteSlide",      ".quoteDot");
let lectureSlider   = new Slider(1, ".lectureSlide",    ".lectureDot");
let gameSlider      = new Slider(1, ".gameSlide",       ".gameDot");
let softwareSlider  = new Slider(1, ".softwareSlide",   ".softwareDot");
let roboticSlider   = new Slider(1, ".roboticSlide",    ".roboticDot");
let teachingSlider  = new Slider(1, ".teachingSlide",   ".teachingDot");
let streamingSlider = new Slider(1, ".streamingSlide",  ".streamingDot");

quoteSlider.setupSlider();
lectureSlider.setupSlider();
gameSlider.setupSlider();
softwareSlider.setupSlider();
roboticSlider.setupSlider();
teachingSlider.setupSlider();
streamingSlider.setupSlider();
```

This code doesn't work, but I can't understand why.

So here are my questions :

- Did I made an error in my thinking process ? Which one ?
- Where in all this JS stuff I made a mistake ?
- What would have been the solution you'd gave to the teacher knowing the context ?
- Is there something to do better globally ?

Disclaimer : This project is over. I waited on purpose for the end of the time-limit to ask as I didn't want to use other people's code to get points for this class.

Thanks for your help, and sorry for that so long text.

Answer (score -1):

Your thinking process is good about making a single class object for this.

First mistake is that everything that defined within root of the class can be accessed within the class by using `this.` prefix, but you were trying access it by their name only, strangely the only place you used it correctly besides the constructor is in the `console.log(this.slideIndex)`

There is no way of stopping the automated slides - that could be improved. Also, in some situations it's better provide slides content via javascript rather than hard code into HTML, use HTML as a template instead.

```js
class Slider {

  slideIndex = 1;
  slides;
  dots;

  constructor(index = 1, sel) {
    this.slideIndex = index;
    const container = document.querySelector(sel);
    this.slides = container.querySelectorAll(".slide");
    const dots = container.querySelector(".dotContainer");
    dots.innerHTML = "";
    this.dots = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < this.slides.length; i++)
    {
      const dot = document.createElement("span");
      dot.className = "dot";
      dot.addEventListener("click", e => this.currentSlide(i + 1));
      dots.appendChild(dot);
      this.dots[i] = dot;
    }
    const nav = container.querySelector(".nav");
    nav.innerHTML = "";
    const prev = document.createElement("a");
    prev.className = "prev";
    prev.addEventListener("click", e => this.plusSlides(-1));
    prev.innerHTML = "&#10094;";
    nav.appendChild(prev);
    const next = document.createElement("a");
    next.className = "next";
    next.addEventListener("click", e => this.plusSlides(-1));
    next.innerHTML = "&#10095;";
    nav.appendChild(next);
  }

  plusSlides(n) {
    this.showSlides(this.slideIndex += n);
  }

  currentSlide(n) {
    this.showSlides(this.slideIndex = n);
  }

  showSlides(n) {
    var i;

    if (n > this.slides.length) {
      this.slideIndex = 1;
    }

    if (n < 1) {
      this.slideIndex = this.slides.length;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < this.slides.length; i++) {
      this.slides[i].style.display = i == this.slideIndex - 1 ? "block" : "none";
    }

    for (i = 0; i < this.dots.length; i++) {
      this.dots[i].classList.toggle("activeDot", i == this.slideIndex-1);
    }

  }

  timer = null;
  stopSlider()
  {
    clearInterval(this.timer);
  }
  setupSlider(speed) {
    this.showSlides(this.slideIndex);

    if (speed === undefined)
      speed = 5000;

    // Sliding automation
    clearInterval(this.timer);
    this.timer = setInterval(() => {
      this.plusSlides(1);
      console.log(this.slideIndex);
    }, speed);
  }
}

let quoteSlider = new Slider(1, ".quoteSlide");
quoteSlider.setupSlider(1000);
/*
let lectureSlider = new Slider(1, ".lectureSlide", ".lectureDot");
let gameSlider = new Slider(1, ".gameSlide", ".gameDot");
let softwareSlider = new Slider(1, ".softwareSlide", ".softwareDot");
let roboticSlider = new Slider(1, ".roboticSlide", ".roboticDot");
let teachingSlider = new Slider(1, ".teachingSlide", ".teachingDot");
let streamingSlider = new Slider(1, ".streamingSlide", ".streamingDot");

lectureSlider.setupSlider();
gameSlider.setupSlider();
softwareSlider.setupSlider();
roboticSlider.setupSlider();
teachingSlider.setupSlider();
streamingSlider.setupSlider();
*/
```

```css
.sliderContainer {
  position: relative;
  background: #eee;
  /* Not useful here */
}

.slide {
  display: none;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -30px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: #444;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

.next {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  /* Changes color and background color */
}

.dotContainer {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  background-color: #444;
  /* still not useful but I let it */
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.activeDot,
.dot:hover {
  /* changes background-color */
}

q {
  /* changes font-style */
}

.author {
  /* changes color */
}
```

```html
<!-- Unrelated content -->
<div class="quoteSlide">
  <div class="sliderContainer">
    <div class="slide">
      <q>A quote</q>
      <p class="author">The quote's author</p>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <q>Another quote</q>
      <p class="author">The quote's author</p>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and Right buttons -->
    <div class="nav">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dotContainer">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
My bad for `this.`
I tried using it but it didn't work either in the way I wrote the code. The one you see is one I forgot to delete.
I'll need to look into your code and see how it's done, and then i'll give you a feedback about it

Comment: Yeah, I'll add comments later, ran out of time right now.

Answer (score -1):

Your approach is very good and i found only three issues:

- You have to call vars and functions of that class inside of it with `this.` for "saying" in which context the var or function is used.
- You don't need to declare the three vars `slideIndex`, `slides` and `dots` at the beginning because this is already done in the constructor.
- The inline event listeners don't work with that OOP structure. Therefor you should add them to the function `setupSlider()`.

Because the usage of a container class is the easiest way for selecting the `.prev`- and `.next`-buttons in the setup function, you should give it to the constructor, for example: `let quoteSlider = new Slider(1, ".quotes");`. You can omit the specific classes, like `.quoteSlide` or `.quoteDot`, if you simply add in the constructor `' .slide'` or  `' .dot'` to the container class in the selector. Of course you have to give that container class to the containers, for example: `class="sliderContainer quotes"` and `class="dotContainer quotes"`.

**Working example:**

```js
class Slider {

  constructor(index = 1, container) {
    this.slideIndex = index;
    this.container = container;
    this.slides = document.querySelectorAll(container + " .slide");
    this.dots = document.querySelectorAll(container + " .dot");
  }

  plusSlides(n) {
    this.showSlides(this.slideIndex += n);
  }

  currentSlide(n) {
    this.showSlides(this.slideIndex = n);
  }

  showSlides(n) {
    var i;

    if (n > this.slides.length) {
      this.slideIndex = 1;
    }

    if (n < 1) {
      this.slideIndex = this.slides.length;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < this.slides.length; i++) {
      this.slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    for (i = 0; i < this.dots.length; i++) {
      this.dots[i].className = this.dots[i].className.replace(" activeDot", "");
    }

    this.slides[this.slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    this.dots[this.slideIndex - 1].className += " activeDot";
  }

  setupSlider() {
    document.querySelector(this.container + " .prev").addEventListener("click",
      e => this.plusSlides(-1)
    );

    document.querySelector(this.container + " .next").addEventListener("click",
      e => this.plusSlides(1)
    );

    for (let i = 0; i < this.dots.length; i++) {
      this.dots[i].addEventListener("click", e => this.currentSlide(i + 1));
    }

    this.showSlides(this.slideIndex);

    // Sliding automation
    setInterval(() => {
      this.plusSlides(1);
    }, 5000);
  }

}

$(document).ready(function() {

  let quoteSlider = new Slider(1, ".quotes");
  let lectureSlider = new Slider(1, ".lectures");
  let gameSlider = new Slider(1, ".games");
  let softwareSlider = new Slider(1, ".software");
  let roboticSlider = new Slider(1, ".robotics");
  let teachingSlider = new Slider(1, ".teachings");
  let streamingSlider = new Slider(1, ".streaming");

  quoteSlider.setupSlider();
  lectureSlider.setupSlider();
  gameSlider.setupSlider();
  softwareSlider.setupSlider();
  roboticSlider.setupSlider();
  teachingSlider.setupSlider();
  streamingSlider.setupSlider();

});
```

```css
.sliderContainer {
  position: relative;
  background: #eee;
  /* Not useful here */
}

.slide {
  display: none;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -30px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: #444;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

.next {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  /* Changes color and background color */
}

.dotContainer {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  background-color: #444;
  /* still not useful but I let it */
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.activeDot,
.dot:hover {
  /* changes background-color */
}

q {
  /* changes font-style */
}

.author {
  /* changes color */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-color/2.1.2/jquery.color.min.js"></script>

<div class="sliderContainer quotes">
  <div class="slide">
    <q>A quote</q>
    <p class="author">The quote's author</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <q>Another quote</q>
    <p class="author">The quote's other author</p>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and Right buttons -->
  <a class="prev">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<div class="dotContainer quotes">
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
</div>

<div class="sliderContainer lectures">
  <div class="slide">
    <q>A lecture</q>
    <p class="author">The lecture's author</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <q>Another lecture</q>
    <p class="author">The lecture's other author</p>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and Right buttons -->
  <a class="prev">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<div class="dotContainer lectures">
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
</div>

<div class="sliderContainer games">
  <div class="slide">
    <q>A game</q>
    <p class="author">The game's author</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <q>Another game</q>
    <p class="author">The game's other author</p>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and Right buttons -->
  <a class="prev">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<div class="dotContainer games">
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
</div>

<div class="sliderContainer software">
  <div class="slide">
    <q>A software</q>
    <p class="author">The software's author</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <q>Another software</q>
    <p class="author">The software's other author</p>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and Right buttons -->
  <a class="prev">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<div class="dotContainer software">
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
</div>

<div class="sliderContainer robotics">
  <div class="slide">
    <q>A robotic</q>
    <p class="author">The robotic's author</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <q>Another robotic</q>
    <p class="author">The robotic's other author</p>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and Right buttons -->
  <a class="prev">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<div class="dotContainer robotics">
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
</div>

<div class="sliderContainer teachings">
  <div class="slide">
    <q>A teaching</q>
    <p class="author">The teaching's author</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <q>Another teaching</q>
    <p class="author">The teaching's other author</p>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and Right buttons -->
  <a class="prev">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<div class="dotContainer teachings">
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
</div>

<div class="sliderContainer streaming">
  <div class="slide">
    <q>A streaming</q>
    <p class="author">The streaming's author</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <q>Another streaming</q>
    <p class="author">The streaming's other author</p>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and Right buttons -->
  <a class="prev">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<div class="dotContainer streaming">
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
</div>
```